# What are the required skills to work on Magento 2 Front-end?

Tags: magento2, frontend, less

I am a fresh front-end developer and I want to start working with Magento 2.

I would like to know what are the required skills to start working on the Luma theme as a first step?

With what grid is Magento 2 working? CSS grid or bootstrap flex?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Welcome to the community.

You can follow the devdocs by Magento.

http://devdocs.magento.com/

For [Frontend Developer Guide](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/frontend-dev-guide/bk-frontend-dev-guide.html) follow this link.

If you are interested in theme designing than you can follow [Theme development](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/howdoi/frontend/front-theme.html) guide.

To include external bootstrap file [Include Bootstrap](https://cedcommerce.com/blog/using-bootstrap-in-magento-2-0/) you can follow this tutorial.

Magento 2 uses LESS to know more how to compile them follow their guide  [CSS and LESS](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/frontend-dev-guide/css-topics/css-preprocess.html)

> Magento 2 does not use any bootstrap it has its's own classes and grid.

Magento 2 now comes with Less and Luma theme which is well implemented.

Magento 2 [Common layout customization tasks](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/xml-manage.html)

Magento 2 [Mage 2 Tech Stack](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/architecture/tech-stack.html)

Update : Learn about Magento [Modes](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/config-guide/bootstrap/magento-modes.html)  i.e default/developer/production

> Always be in developer mode while working at code level to set developer mode use

Change To Developer Mode Using Command Line

`php bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer`

Comment: If the answer helps you please accept or we can try to explore more to help each other. Thank You

Comment: welcome @JonathanBen sir